# How can I make the overlapping part to be transparent same as surrounding?

Tags: visio

How can I make this blur (transparent) same as the surrounding part? 
The problem is that it's an overlapping of two lines.

[image]

I created this by drawing a line and then add arrow like this.

[image]

Comment: No way! Because in Visio each shape such as curved line cannot have one part 100% transparent and the other part a certain color

Comment: @Surrogate: Thanks, not a good new though :D. So there is no way around to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting behavior.
Surrogate is write in that it can't be solved with standard functions.
But there are at least 2 workaround (with some disadvantages)

1. use custom line end and make sure its left boundary does not touch the left side of the arrow head. Caveat: instead of an overlapping, you get a gap.
2. use a custom line pattern with the whole arrow already drawn. Draw it as 1 shape.
   Caveat:
   a) ONE length - otherwise the head is stretched.
   b) The arrow head is curved as well.
   I cannot upload here. If you repost you question to http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php I can upload there.

Comment: I try your example from [VisioGuy post](http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=9902.msg45265#msg45265), I modify stowed line ends for make it filled and middle-left. [Overlap is minimal](https://imgur.com/3TXhLjk) !

Answer (score 0):

Try use grey lines with 0% transparency instead black line with 60% transparency!

Comment: I did this but I wanted transparent arrow so it doesn't block background instead.